# Shopware 6 - Get translation for product name and description

Tags: shopware6

I want to retrieve my products name and description in different languages.

Currently, I use the `RepositoryIterator` to fetch products from the database like this:

```php
return new RepositoryIterator(
    $this->productRepository,
    $this->getSalesChannelContext($salesChannelId)->getContext(),
    $criteria
);
```

When I loop through these products and use this for example:

```php
$product->getTranslation('name')
$product->getName()
```

In all cases, the name is the product name in english language, despite I have multiple languages in one SalesChannel and the products are maintained in multiple languages. I am not able to get to the other translations. Also the function `getTranslated()` on the product gives an array with the english name.

I have found only this workaround to get the translations currently:

1. Within my criteria for the `RepositoryIterator` I add the translations relation `$criteria->addAssociation("translations");`
2. After that I can do this:

```php
$translations = $product->getTranslations()->filterByLanguageId($germanLanguageId);

/** @var ProductTranslationEntity $elements */
$elements = current($translations->getElements());

$elements->getName();
```

This will get the name in german language then. But this can not be the regular case, right? There must be a way to tell the Context within the RepositoryIterator to be the german language so that `getTranslation` or `getTranslated` or even `getName` will work properly and return the name in the desired language, am I right?

I have the issue that I work with the `OrderLineItemEntity` as well and here I also have the `getTranslation` or `getTranslated` function, but both always give the english translation.

How can I solve this? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The language to be used for the translation is determined by the language chain of the context. With the first language in the chain having the highest priority and, given there is no translation for that language, the following languages in the chain being used as fallbacks in that order.

You can take the original context, clone it (if you want to avoid mutating it for the rest of the stack), and assign a new language chain. In the new chain you can then put your desired language up front.

```php
$context = clone $this->getSalesChannelContext($salesChannelId)->getContext();
$context = $context->assign([
    'languageIdChain' => array_unique([$languageId, ...$context->getLanguageIdChain()]),
]);

return new RepositoryIterator(
    $this->productRepository,
    $context,
    $criteria
);
```

Alternatively, as it seems you're creating the `SalesChannelContext` on the fly and assuming you're using `SalesChannelContextFactory::create` to do so, you can also provide the language specifically when creating the context.

```php
$salesChannelContext = $this->salesChannelContextFactory->create(
    $token, 
    $salesChannelId, 
    [SalesChannelContextService::LANGUAGE_ID => $languageId]
);
```

Comment: Hey @dneustadt, thanks for your quick and extensive explanation. I just found out the second way by my own. What I am asking myself now is, when I use the RepositoryIterator with the languageId in the Context, does this implicate the SQL query in the way that the languageId is always queried? Because I query the languageId in my Criteria optionally. Can I set the languageId in the context, even when it should not impact the results by the Criteria when the language is not set in the Criteria?

Comment: For the translations it's not necessary to set up the criteria like that. The DAL will resolve the translations by the languages set in the context.

Comment: Okay, thats what I thought. So I can restrict the Criteria to a language or non at all, but use the language in the Context every time. I experienced that getName populates the name in the desired language of the context then, but when do I use getTranslation(‘name’) or getTranslated()? Because I can not use these functions when the language in the Context is missing? Or can I use these two functions when I have multiple functions in the languageChain and with these methods I can switch between them?

Comment: As a rule of thumb: When you need all or a subset of possible translations, add the association `translations` and call `getTranslations`. If you need a specific translation create the context accordingly and use the specific getter for the translated property, e.g. `getName`. The `getTranslated` method is mostly then useful if the property may be dynamic e.g. `getTranslated($property)`.

Comment: Thanks. To be clear, `getTranslated()` and `getTranslation(key)` has mostly the same purpose? I used the association `translations` and `getTranslations` yesterday, but then I need to do something like this: `$product->getTranslations()->filterByLanguageId($languageId)->getElements()` and then use getName on the elements? So lastly, when I set the languageId in the Context, I can just use `getName` and `getDescription` and get the correct language for the context and I do not need `getTranslation() / getTranslated` at all, right? Is this also valid when I fetch OrderLineItemEntities?

Comment: Yes, this is all the same regardless of the entity fetched. In most cases you shouldn't even consider `getTranslated` nor `getTranslation`. Just use the respective getter, when you set the language when creating the context. For instance `getTranslated()['name']`, `getTranslation('name')` and `getName()` should all yield the same value. Meanwhile `getTranslations` gets you a collection of all the translations, including those of `name`, given you added the `translations` criteria.